# Enhancing confidence in automatically chosen review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

It seems that mostly audits (mostly referring to VLQ) are chosen from existing questions/answers when those have a rather good records. Only upvotes, no flags/close/delete votes etc. and still some of them slip through and become failed audits because reviewers rightfully vote to close/delete.

We should let the system enhance the confidence of it being a good audit by feeding it through the review queues, and collecting additional results here, but limited to a subset of all users.

Those users should have an above average review records, and quite some reputation in the tags that are related. I don't think it will draw too much resources from necessary reviews that those users can't do then. We could also silently not count those against their daily review limitation to make sure they can use all of their reviews. Important is though that it isn't visible for them immedeately that this was a test if this question is good for a review audit.

Comment: Alternatively, only use fairly recent of such 'good posts'. A post that accumilated lots of upvotes 3 years ago is not necessarily a good post, or even on-topic today. The other way around has a lot less problems I think. Crappy posts from the past are most likely still crappy posts today.